# Mostrar dato de id 1 o mas en php y sql

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero mostrar datos de una base de datos. Esto ya lo sé, pero solo se mostrar lo todo lo que está en el id 0 de la tabla de la base, y ahora quiero mostrar lo que esta en la tabla 2. Por ejemplo

```
 id   dato1   dato2
 0    abc     def
 1    ghi     jkl
```

Bien, lo que está en "ID:0" ya lo se mostrar, pero lo que está en "ID: 1" no se como se muestra, esta es mi metodo para mostrar:

```
$sql_dbdatos = "SELECT * from datos";
$result_dbdatos= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbdatos);
$rows_dbdatos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbdatos);
```

Y esto lo pongo en una tabla:

```
<li>  ' . $rows_dbpartidos['dato1'] . '</li>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? No termina de quedar claro con lo expuesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Ahí edité para que se entienda un poquito mejor.

Comment: `dpartidos` no es una base de datos, es una tabla.  `partido1` no es una tabla, es una columna.  Quiza se entenderia mejor si pusieras la estructura de la tabla `dpartidos`.  Creo que `id` es otra columna en la tabla `dpartidos`?

Comment: Ahi puse una imagen, quiero mostrar lo que dice imagen1 e imagen2, y para conectarme con la base de datos y la tabla tengo ese codigo.

Comment: ¿No es esto lo que necesitas: `SELECT * from dpartidos WHERE id=1`? De ese modo te filtra por `id=1` y si quieres otra cosa, le pones ahí el id de esa *otra cosa*...  O no entendí bien la pregunta, la cual está planteada de una forma algo confusa.

Comment: Quiero mostrar "imagen1" no se como explicarlo, google tampoco me entendió jaja.

Comment: Haciendo la consulta como te indiqué, tendrás en la columna `partido1` el valor `imagen1` y en la columna `partido2`  el valor de `imagen2`... ¿eso es lo que quieres? Y ya hablando de otra cosa, intuyo que estamos ante un pésimo diseño de datos. Yo manejaría todo esto con tablas relacionadas: una sola tabla `equipos` donde tendría los nombres, las imágenes de cada uno, etc. Y en la tabla partidos manejaría sólo los id de los equipos y en base a eso traería lo que fuera. Este diseño que tienes por lo que veo es horrible. Pero bueno, ese es otro tema, lo digo sólo como crítica constructiva.

Comment: Si, quiero eso, pero como lo muestro despues. Puedes crear una respuesta De como sería? Por favor, agradezco tu ayuda, pero no es para criticar esto que yo sepa, no entiendo cual es el sentido de generar esto. si se ayuda se ayuda, y si no, no critiques.

Comment: Ahí tienes una propuesta. Espero te sea de utilidad. Y, acepta de buena gana las críticas constructivas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo mejoraría considerablemente el diseño de datos de la siguiente forma:

- Una tabla `equipos`
- Una tabla `partidos`

Dado que evidentemente es algo sobre el mundial de fútbol, otras tablas serían posibles, como grupos, puntos, etc... pero no nos compliquemos demasiado. Lo importante es **que entiendas que este tipo de cosas hay que resolverlas con tablas relacionadas para evitar la redundancia de datos y facilitar el mantenimiento y la consulta.**

Las tablas **relacionadas** nos permiten usar identificadores (que es generalmente la columna del `id`) para relacionar datos provenientes de diversas tablas, al tiempo que permiten que esos datos no se repitan una y otra vez, ocupando espacio innecesariamente.

> Aquí la tabla `equipos` tendrá una fila por cada equipo y nada más. Y
>   cuando quieras registrar un partido no tendrás que repetir una y otra
>   vez el nombre del equipo en la tabla `partidos`, sino que usarás
>   `equipo_visitante`  y `equipo_local` para identificar los equipos que se enfrentan entre sí en cada partido (eso es lo que se llama *llave foránea*  en base de datos).

Veamos ahora las tablas y sus posibles columnas:

#### tabla `equipos`

```
equipo_id            INT   
equipo_nombre        VARCHAR
equipo_imagen        VARCHAR (O BLOB)

... más columnas si fuera necesario
```

#### tabla `partidos`

```
partido_id           INT AUTO_INCREMENT
equipo_visitante     INT
equipo_local         INT
fecha                DATE
estadio_id           INT

... más columnas si fuera necesario
```

En la tabla `partidos` las columnas `equipo_visitante` y `equipo_local` estarían relacionadas con la tabla `equipos` en la columna `equipo_id`, y la columna `estadio_id` con la tabla columna `estadio_id` de una posible tabla `estadios`... (esto último es para ampliar un poco más el campo de visión de las tablas relacionadas).

---

Veamos un boceto del contenido de las tablas.

En la tabla `equipos` podemos tener algo así. **Habrá una sola fila por equipo**, para evitar la redundancia de datos. Y cuando haya un partido usaremos el `id` de cada equipo para registrarlo, no repetiremos el nombre del equipo cada vez:

```
equipo_id      equipo_nombre       equipo_imagen
1              Inglaterra          uk.jpg
2              Croacia             cr.jpg
3              Bélgica             be.jpg
4              Francia             fr.jpg
```

Y los partidos son gestionados así:

```
partido_id   equipo_visitante    equipo_local    fecha              estadio_id
1              4                      3          2018-07-09 16:00   1
2              1                      2          2018-07-09 20:00   1
```

Por los ids relacionados ya podemos ver que hay:

- Un partido entre Francia y Bélgica en el estadio 1 a las 16 horas de hoy. ¿Cómo sabemos que es Francia y Bélgica? Si te fijas en la 1ª fila, verás que el valor de `equipo_visitante` es `4` y el valor de `equipo_local` es `3`. Si verificas en la tabla `equipos` a quién corresponde el `4` verás que es a Francia, y el `3`  le corresponde a Bélgica. Ese es el fundamento de las bases de datos relacionales. No tienes que repetir millones de veces `Francia` o `Bélgica`  o el equipo que sea, sino solamente usar su `id` y listo.
- Podemos ver también que hay un partido entre Inglatera (equipo visitante) y Croacia (equipo local) en el estadio 1 también pero a las 20 horas de hoy. Te dejo como ejercicio saber por qué en la fila 2 son esos los equipos  que compiten.

Ahora si queremos obtener todos los datos de cualquiera de esos partidos hacemos algo así por ejemplo. Nótese que esta es una entre mil formas de consultas con criterios `WHERE` como los quieras:

```
SELECT 
        ev.equipo_nombre visitante, 
        ev.equipo_imagen img_visitante
        el.equipo_nombre local
        el.equipo_imagen img_local
        p.fecha,
        p.estadio_id
FROM
partidos p 
INNER JOIN equipos ev ON p.equipo_visitante=ev.equipo_id
INNER JOIN equipos el ON p.equipo_local    =el.equipo_id
WHERE p.partido_id=1;
```

Lo que hace esta consulta es unir las tablas por sus columnas relacionadas.

Las uniones ocurren así:

1. La primera tabla que participa en la unión es la del `FROM`.  Si observas la consulta verás que dice `FROM partidos p`. Estamos pues indicando que la 1ª tabla con la que vamos a unir es con `partidos`. La `p`  es un alias, para no tener que escribir a cada rato: `partidos, partidos, partidos`, sino que escribimos `p` y listo.
2. La segunda unión ocurre aquí: `INNER JOIN equipos ev ON p.equipo_visitante=ev.equipo_id` le decimos que una (`INNER JOIN`) la tabla `equipos` con la tabla `partidos` usando las columnas `equipo_visitante` y `equipo_id` en cada una respectivamente. Además, le hemos dado un alias a la tabla `equipos` para esta unión, el cual es `ev` (iniciales de equipo visitante... ahí tú le puedes poner lo que quieras, le puedes poner hasta pedrito como alias, le he dado `ev` por convención de nombres, para entender que las columnas de esa tabla son las del equipo visitante).
3. La tercera unión ocurre aquí: `INNER JOIN equipos el ON p.equipo_local=el.equipo_id`. Le decimos que una **de nuevo**  la tabla `equipos` con la tabla `partidos`, usando siempre la columna `equipo_id` en la tabla `equipos` **pero en la tabla `partidos` le decimos que use otra columna que es `equipo_local`**. De esa forma estamos haciendo una doble unión. En una obtenemos los datos de uno de los equipos (2ª unión explicada antes) y en esta obtenemos los datos del otro equipo. Aquí le hemos dado el alias `el`  a la tabla, que son las iniciales de equipo local (llámale juanito si quieres).

   De ese modo tú puedes traer la información de todas las tablas que participan en la relación.

En los criterios `WHERE` tú puedes filtrar por fecha, por id de equipo, por estadio o por lo que necesites.

El resultado de esta consulta será algo así:

```
visitante      img_visitante    local    img_local    fecha             estadio_id
Francia        fr.jpg           Bélgica  be.jpg       2018-07-09 16:00       1
```

Por todo lo **ya** explicado, podrás entender por qué el resultado es el mostrado más arriba y de dónde proviene cada dato.

Las bases de datos existen para hacer este tipo de cosas, y otras más avanzadas. No existen para que te pases la vida repitiendo Equipo X, Equipo Y, Equipo Z, Equipo X, Equipo Y, Equipo Z.... las bases de datos manejan identificadores y usan esos identificadores para traer los datos que hagan falta.

Espero que ahora entiendas mejor de que se trata. Estos son sólo principios muy básicos de bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: Hola, ahí esto haciendo como me dijiste, agradezco que te tomaras el tiempo de crear todo esto. Podrías explicarme un poco la parte del "_SELECT..._", como el funcionamiento y como se usa? Para mostrar lo de la base.

Comment: Esta parte: `SELECT 
        ev.equipo_nombre visitante, 
        ev.equipo_imagen img_visitante
        el.equipo_nombre local
        el.equipo_imagen img_local
        p.fecha,
        p.estadio_id
FROM
partidos p 
INNER JOIN equipos ev ON p.equipo_visitante=ev.equipo_id
INNER JOIN equipos el ON p.equipo_local    =el.equipo_id
WHERE p.partido_id=1;` No explicas como va.

Comment: la idea @MatiPHP es que corrijas tu estructura, pues tu esquema de bases de datos no tiene sentido; darte una respuesta sobre lo que muestras es dar una respuesta pero a una pregunta con un contenido incorrecto

Comment: Yo quiero mostrar el texto imagen1 e imagen2, solo solo, nada mas, creo que no se entendió.

Comment: @MatiPHP voy a editar la respuesta tratando de explicar un poco más, aunque me parecía que estaba bastante claro... Editando.........  ...... .......

Comment: Pero no entiendo como pongo en mi pagina `SELECT 
        ev.equipo_nombre visitante, 
        ev.equipo_imagen img_visitante
        el.equipo_nombre local
        el.equipo_imagen img_local
        p.fecha,
        p.estadio_id
FROM
partidos p 
INNER JOIN equipos ev ON p.equipo_visitante=ev.equipo_id
INNER JOIN equipos el ON p.equipo_local    =el.equipo_id
WHERE p.partido_id=1;`

Comment: @MatiPHP pues donde tenías esta consulta: `SELECT * from dpartidos`  la cambias por la consulta que propongo en la respuesta.

Comment: No me queda, me queda de color rosa y variables o lo que sea esto "el.equipo_imagen" me queda violeta

Comment: No sé que quieres decir con te que queda con color rosa y con color violeta... revisa la sintaxis, no sea que tengas comillas de más o de menos en alguna parte o llaves sin cerrar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79999/discussion-between-matiphp-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Perdón, sinceramente no te entiendo, no entiendo para que te tomaste el tiempo en crear todo eso, si yo quería mostrar solo el texto imagen1 que estaba en el id 1 de la base de datos.

Comment: Asi me conecto: $sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from dpartidos";
$result_dbpartidos = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbpartidos);
$rows_dbpartidos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbpartidos);

Comment: Quiero crear otra pregunta, pero me la van a eliminar porque está esta que la única respuesta no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: Cambia esta consulta: `SELECT * from dpartidos` por esta otra: `SELECT  ev.equipo_imagen img_visitante, el.equipo_imagen img_local FROM partidos p INNER JOIN equipos ev ON p.equipo_visitante=ev.equipo_id INNER JOIN equipos el ON p.equipo_local =el.equipo_id WHERE p.partido_id=1`  así obtendrás las imágenes. Pruébalo en la base de datos. Me he tomado un buen rato tratando de explicarte las cosas lo más claro posible, pero no sé si te has detenido a analizar la respuesta. La intención además es ayudarte para que en un futuro no hagas malos diseños que te van a complicar la existencia.

Comment: Ya lo probé, y me aparecen las letras en violeta. Si me tome el tiempo de leerlo, no una, ni dos, mas de tres veces leí todo, pero en esa parte algo no está bien. Igual dejémoslo acá ya que no se entendió la pregunta.